# Getting "Type or namespace Serializable does not exist in the namespace..." error in wp8 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, protobuf-net

So I'm pretty new to this protobuf-net stuff as well as wp8 development and I'm having an issue using the protogen generated .cs file in my project. Specifically this line of the file:

```
  [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"Person_PB")]
```

Causes the error message in the question title.  I have been having other issues in my code trying to use Serialization as well.

```
using (var file = File.Create("person.bin")) {
    Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
}
```

Serializer is not recognized and I don't know what to add at the top of the file to fix it (ie what 'using' thing to add)

Anyone know what to include in my project so that Serialization works?

Comment: To address the other part of my question involving using Serializer. Serialize(file, person) to serialize the data within my wp8 project. I just used the DataContractSerializer class detailed here Data http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752244.aspx along with the StorageFile classes detailed here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tweak how you call protogen; IIRC (I'm not at a PC) adding: `-p:lightFramework` should fix this for you. The issue here is that `[Serializable]` simply doesn't exist on all frameworks.

For info, `-p:help` should tell you all the available options.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I had a heck of a time trying to figure this stuff all out.